# Angular 5 view not refreshing after data update

Tags: angular

In my component I have an attribute (called qcHoldExceptions). I am adding 
a record to this in the database and then a try to refresh the attribute by calling a service (get from database). However, my view is not updating with the new elements. I'm I've tried different ways but it wont update. Once I refresh the page, the new data shows up fine.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

My Component:

```
qcHoldExceptions: Observable<QcHoldException[]>;


setQcHoldExceptions(){
    this.qcHoldExceptions = this.qcHoldExService.getQcHoldExceptionByCategory(this.qcHoldCategory.qcHoldCategoryId);
}
```

My View:

```
<li  *ngFor="let exception of qcHoldExceptions | async" (click)="selectQcHoldException(exception)" class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'selected-list-item':exception === selectedQcHoldException  }" >
  <a>{{exception.qcHoldException}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Where and when setQcHoldExceptions|() gets called after you add a record to the database?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Subject`?

Comment: Anik - yes it gets callled after I add a record. I've done a console.log to ensure that it is called, which it is.  Ive also tried with defining qcHoldExceptions: QcHoldException[]. Then I subscribe to my service and set qcHoldExceptions explicitly as well.

Comment: Damien - never looked at Subject, I will check into yet

Comment: Do you have changedetectionstrategy set up? Also are you sure `qcHoldExceptions` has correct value and it is just not rendered? What if you resize window/click somewhere? Does it trigger the refresh?

Comment: Sharikov - change detection isn't setup. qcHoldExceptions does have the correct value in it. I notice that after I add a second value, then the 1st value shows up. After third, the second shows up, etc. Its like there is a delay and its not picked up. I'll try to resize and see what happens.